# Returning max value and value prior

Tags: sql, oracle, max, top-n

I have a query I run to tell me the latest note for active participants:

```
select notes.applicant_id,
   reg.program_code,
   reg.last_name,
   reg.first_name,
   reg.status_cd,
   MAX(notes.service_date) as "Last Note"
from reg inner join notes on reg.applicant_id=notes.applicant_id
where reg.status_cd='AC'
group by notes.applicant_id, reg.program_code, 
         reg.last_name, reg.first_name, reg.reg_date, 
         reg.region_code, reg.status_cd
order by MAX(notes.service_date)
```

But I would also like this query to give me the result of the `note.service_date` just prior to the max `service_date` as well.

Results would look like this

```
notes.applicant_id   reg.last_name  reg.first_name reg.status_cd  Last Note    Prior Note
 12345                 Johnson          Lori           AC        01-NOV-2011   01-OCT-2011
```

I am working in oracle.

Comment: If you are using Oracle, please tag the question as such.

Comment: You're trying to mix aggregate and non aggregate values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`lag`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) function, or join it with the same table.

Here is a simpler example (you haven't givven us data sample):

```
create table t as
(select level as id, mod(level , 3) grp, sysdate - level dt
from dual 
connect by level < 100
)
```

and here are the queries:

```
select t2.grp,t1.grp, max(t1.dt) mdt, max(t2.dt) pdt
  from t t1
  join t t2 on t1.dt < t2.dt and t1.grp = t2.grp
 group by t2.grp, t1.grp;
```

or

```
select grp, max(pdt), max(dt)
 from(
 select grp, lag(dt) over (partition by grp order by dt) pdt, dt 
 from t)
 group by grp
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/343df/1) is a fiddle

---

In your case it could be something like this:

```
select t.applicant_id, t.program_code, 
         t.last_name, t.first_name, t.reg_date, 
         t.region_code, t.status_cd,
         max(t.dt) as "Last Note",
         max(t.pdt) as "Prev Note"
from (
select notes.applicant_id,
   reg.program_code,
   reg.last_name,
   reg.first_name,
   reg.status_cd,
   notes.service_date as dt,
   lag(notes.service_date)  over (partition by notes.applicant_id,
   reg.program_code,
   reg.last_name,
   reg.first_name,
   reg.status_cd order by notes.service_date) as pdt
from reg inner join notes on reg.applicant_id=notes.applicant_id
where reg.status_cd='AC'
) t
group by t.applicant_id, t.program_code, 
         t.last_name, t.first_name, t.reg_date, 
         t.region_code, t.status_cd
order by MAX(t.dt)
```

Comment: I don't have the capability to create tables.  I only get to retrieve data.

Comment: @user1466935, you don't need to create tables - this was just a simple example. Use the same idea on **your** table. See the query at the buttom of the answer

Comment: A.B. Cade---Thank you for answering this question.  I'm now interested in seeing the author of the notes.service_date for that Last Note.  Is it possible to use lag on two different columns within the same query?  Since notes can be put in by any user, I would need the author of the t.dt column.  The column name is notes.author . Would appreciate any help you could give, I've been studying this today to no avail.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, here's one way to do it:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (select notes.applicant_id,
               reg.program_code,
               reg.last_name,
               reg.first_name,
               reg.status_cd,
               notes.service_date AS "Last Note",
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY notes.applicant_id, reg.program_code, 
                   reg.last_name, reg.first_name, reg.reg_date, reg.region_code, 
                   reg.status_cd ORDER BY notes.service_date DESC) rn
          from reg inner join notes on reg.applicant_id=notes.applicant_id
         where reg.status_cd='AC')
 WHERE rn < 3;
```

Comment: Works!  Thank you!  I never thought about using row and partition.

Comment: Would there be anyway to put all this in one row by notes.applicant.id ?  Right now I see 2 rows of information for each person, it would be great if I could see it in just one row.